# IIS Change PHP.ini location

Tags: php, iis, iis-7

I am a novice with IIS on Windows Server 2008

My question is basically how to change the path of PHP.ini, due to `phpinfo();` my PHP configuration is loaded from `C:\windows` when I have my mapped module linked to:

```
C:\PHP5.4
```

So How would I go about changing this around, I have performed some research into this subject, but it has not provided me with a solution.

I am on WIndows Server 2008 Running IIS 6.0 with a mapped module of PHP5.4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Windows, you can set the search location in the registry.

Via the [PHP Configuration File](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php):

> - As of PHP 5.2.0, the location of the php.ini file can be set for different versions of PHP. The following registry keys are examined in order: [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PHP\x.y.z], [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PHP\x.y] and [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PHP\x], where x, y and z mean the PHP major, minor and release versions. If there is a value for IniFilePath in any of these keys, the first one found will be used as the location of the php.ini (Windows only).
> - [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\PHP], value of IniFilePath (Windows only).